# Input number to add new text box Vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuex, handler, vuejs3

I want to try handle add new inutbox. I try to follow this example
https://demo.smarttutorials.net/vuejs-dynamically-add-remove-input-textbox/
but I can't do

This is i want todo
When i type number in inputbox

add new inputbox

if input 1 add 1
if input 2 add 2 box

[image: example]

My code

```
    <DialogTitle as="h3" class="text-xl leading-6 font-medium text-gray-900 py-2">Transaction #1</DialogTitle>
   <input type="text"  v-model="inputs.sequence" @inputs='$emit("update:modelValue", inputs)' class="border border-gray-300 py-2 px-1 text-lg" />


export default {
  name:'prize-editor',
  components: {
    DropImages,
    date,
    DialogTitle
  },
  props:{
    modelValue:Object
  },
  setup(props){
    let inputs = ref({
      detail:'',
      name:'',
      startDate:'',
      sequence:'',
      rewardId:'',
      imageUrl:"",
    })

    onMounted( () => {
      inputs.value=props.modelValue
    });
    watch(props.modelValue, (value) => {
      inputs.value = value
      console.log('watch',value)
    })
    return{
      inputs,  
    }
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have given little info about how those inputs are supposed to behave exactly, but if we imagine you want to store (and do something with) the value of each, you need an array. and a function that adds as many elements to that array as you put in the input (how you call the function is up to you):

```
addInput(number) {
  for(let i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    this.inputArray.push({ value: "" });
  }
}
```

Then you need to use `v-for` to render inputs based on your array :

```
<input v-for="(input, index) in inputArray" :key="index" v-model="input.value" type="text" />
```

To access the elements you can use index (like `inputArray[2].value` for the third input's value).

Comment: Can you help me make an example? Or is there any documentation and video on this? I do not understand
In the image and code are Chilean component . and i prop data from parent component I want to type number in the Prize Quantity and add a new inputbox transaction. Sorry, I'm an intern and I need a lot of practice, if my typing doesn't make sense, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a full vue component with your what you want, note that its based on options api and has no styles, those are on yourself:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" v-model="inputCounter" />
    <button @click="setInputs">Set</button>
    <input v-for="(input, index) in inputs" :key="index" v-model="input.value" type="text" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default ({
  data() {
    return {
      inputCounter: "",

      inputs: []
    }
  },

  methods: {
    setInputs() {
      for(let i = 0; i < parseInt(this.inputCounter); i++) {
        this.inputs.push({ value: "" });
      }
    }
  }
})
</script>
```